# Navigator.getUserMedia() returns permission denied when run on android phone

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, getusermedia

I'm trying to launch camera on android 6.0.0 with Web APIs. Below is the piece of code which works perfectly on web browser.

```
    var constraints = {
                    video: true,
                    audio: false,
            }

    // get the media sources
    MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sourceInfos) {

            navigator.getUserMedia( constraints, function(stream){
                domElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }, function(error) {
                    console.error("Cant getUserMedia()! due to ", error);
            });
    });
```

I have bundled this piece of code into an apk with ionic framework. But on the phone, it displays a broken video playback image.

On further debugging I noticed "permission denied" error is thrown. I'm not exactly sure for which reason this error is thrown. I googled and have done all the solutions provided. But it has not worked for me.

If I try to build it via phoneGap, it shows NavigatorUserMediaError {name: "PermissionDeniedError", message: "Only secure origins are allowed (see: some URL).", constraintName: ""}

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this answer.

http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera

**Example Usage**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>PhoneGap Example</name>

    <description>
        An example for phonegap build docs. 
    </description>

    <author href="https://build.phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        Hardeep Shoker 
    </author>

    <!--
      If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
      following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
      permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

    <!-- to enable individual permissions use the following examples -->
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: I would appreciate if I get a solution which does not use phonegap. I'm not so familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an issue with Android Runtime Permissions. [Here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getusermedia-broken-in-latest-versions-of-ionic-and-crosswalk/57553/6) you can see an answer of this to a discussion in Ionic. This problem occurs in an obscure way, but all resides in the [Android 6 Runtime Permissions system](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). You can solve it by [adding the permissions to your manifest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-opentok-android-permissions) and [requesting the runtime permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#requestruntimepermission).